# How to write digits in x64 Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

So I have been trying to print digits in x64 assembly nasm program and my source code is this:

```
section .data
    digit: db 0, 10

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 6
    mov rbx, 2
    div rbx
    call _printRAXDigit

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

_printRAXDigit:
    add rax, 48
    mov [digit], al
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, digit
    mov rdi, 2
    syscall
    ret
```

But the output is **empty** and nothing appears. Is there a problem with my code or assembler

**UPDATE:**
CherryDT found the answer it was that I typed `rdi` instead `rdx`

Comment: Yes, you accidentally typed `rdi` a second time instead of `rdx` (so you wrote an undefined number of characters depending on previous contents of `rdx` - probably zero - to `stderr`, i.e. FD 2, instead of printing 2 characters to `stdout`). I recommend learning how to use a debugger, you could then easily observe that this is happening if you break on the `syscall` and check the registers.

Comment: Use `strace ./a.out` to see what args you pass to system calls.  e.g. that you passed length = 0 (the remainder from `div`, which didn't fault since this is presumably built into a static executable so RDX was zero before the division as well).  Basic debugging would have caught this typo, closing as a duplicate mostly as a typo.